# Correct length of VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pSampleMask

Tags: c, graphics, vulkan

Unlike other Vulkan's structs, where all `type pArrayName*;` has a companion `uint32_t arrayNameCount` with array length, struct  `VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo` does not define any `sampleMaskCount` for field `const VkSampleMask* pSampleMask;`.

The [Vulkan docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.html) says the following about valid usage:

> *"If pSampleMask is not NULL, pSampleMask must be a pointer to an array of ⌈rasterizationSamples / 32⌉ VkSampleMask values."*

But  `VkSampleCountFlagBits rasterizationSamples;` is a bitwise value:

> rasterizationSamples is a VkSampleCountFlagBits specifying the number of samples per pixel used in rasterization.

So far so good.

But VkSampleCountFlagBits is a enumeration of power of 2 values, ranging from 0x01 to 0x40 (or 01 to 64 decimal). Possible ANDed values may ranges from 01 to 127.
So I guess bitwise values ranging from 1 to 31 will result in a `pSampleMask`  with length 0; values from 32 to 63 will give length 2, and so on.

Is that correct ? 
I'm felling really really dumb !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When they say "rasterizationSamples" in the formula they almost certainly mean "the number of rasterization samples", not "the value of the rasterizationSamples bitmask".

Additionally, ⌈...⌉ means to round up to the nearest integer.

So, for rasterization sample counts from 1 to 32 (bitmask values 0x01 to 0x20), pSampleMask points to a single value. For rasterization sample counts from 33 to 64 (bitmask value 0x40), it points to an array of two values.

I notice that the bitmask's value line up with the description of each bit (64 has the value 64, and so on) but it could be coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

The `rasterizationSamples` must be only one of the `SampleCountFlagBits` values (**not** a bitwised | value).

Simply speaking, then you need the amount of bits in `pSampleMask` array (consisting of 32 b values) to be greater or equal to the amount of samples as specified by `rasterizationSamples`. (i.e. one `VkSampleMask := uint32_t` for all of them except for `SAMPLE_COUNT_64`, which needs two)

It is somewhat funny that they didn't choose single uint64_t for the purpose. (maybe they plan adding 128 samples :)